# Anyone facing ValueError for RSIIndicator for ta backtesting?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, back-testing

Trying to get some idea on how to debug this. Just started to use backtesting.py + TA to conduct some backtesting. Seems to work for EMA indicator. RSI indicator did not work: Tried with `self.rsi` instead of `self.rsi [-1]` as well. But the same ValueError was raised.

Error seems to start from backtesting.py on line 139:

> File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\backtesting\backtesting.py:139, in >Strategy.I(self, func, name, plot, overlay, color, scatter, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence.

Was expecting RSI Indicator to work like any other indicators.

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import ta
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy, set_bokeh_output
from backtesting.lib import crossover

df = yf.download('AAPL', start='2022-12-01', end='2023-12-31')

class EMA_200(Strategy):

n1 = 200
n2 = 14
rsi_btm = 30
rsi_top = 70

def init(self):
    close = self.data.Close
    self.ema_200 = self.I(ta.trend.ema_indicator, pd.Series(close), self.n1)
    self.rsi = self.I(ta.momentum.RSIIndicator, pd.Series(close), self.n2)

def next(self):
    if self.data.index[-1] >= pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01'):
        if not self.position: # no existing position
            if (self.data.Close < self.ema_200) and (self.rsi[-1] <= self.rsi_btm):
                self.buy()
            elif self.data.Close > self.ema_200 and (self.rsi[-1] >= self.rsi_top):
                self.sell()
        elif self.position: # existing position
            if (self.position.is_long) and (self.data.Close > self.ema_200) and (self.rsi[-1] >= self.rsi_top):
                self.position.close()
            elif (self.position.is_short) and (self.data.Close < self.ema_200) and (self.rsi[-1] >= self.rsi_btm):
                self.position.close()
bt = Backtest(df, EMA_200, cash=1000000, commission=.002,
exclusive_orders=True)
stats = bt.run()
stats
```

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue with the StochasticRSI.
self.I takes in a function, this function should return an array of the same length of (price) data https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/doc/backtesting/backtesting.html#backtesting.backtesting.Strategy.I

However, StochRSIIndicator & RSIIndicator do not return indicator data arrays they return an indicator object.
The array can be accessed using the stochrsi()/rsi() method.

The example below is how I got it sorted for StochRSIIndicator. Should be the same for RSIIndicator but using the rsi() method.

```
rsi = lambda : StochRSIIndicator(close=close, window=self.RSI_WINDOW).stochrsi()
self.rsi = self.I(rsi)
```

Please do not hesitate to respond to this with a cleaner solution should you find one.